# pytest: How to execute setup code only if a certain fixture is loaded

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, pytest

I’m developing database based flask application (using flask-sqlalchemy). I use fixtures to define individual pieces of test data.

```py
@pytest.fixture(scope='class')
def model_a(db):
   a = ModelA()
   db.session.add(a)
   db.session.commit()
   return a


@pytest.fixture(scope='class')
def model_b(db, a):
  b = ModelB(a=a)
  db.session.add(b)
  db.session.commit()
  return b

# …
```

While it works to call `db.session.commit()` for each and every test object it would be more efficient to call it only once right before  executing the actual tests.

Is there a way to run `db.session.commit()` before every test, after all fixtures are loaded, but only if the test directly or indirectly needs `db`?

---

Things that I don’t think that they will work:

- A `python_runtest_setup`-hook doesn’t seem to be able to access fixtures or to determine whether the `db` fixture is loaded for/required by the test.
- A autouse fixture would need to depend on `db` and thus make all tests use the `db` fixture. Also I couldn’t find a way to make it executed last.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't specify fixtures ordering other than indirectly (fixtures depending on other fixtures), see discussion in [issue #1216](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/1216). You can access both fixture names and fixture values in hooks though, so using a hook is actually a good idea. However, `pytest_runtest_setup` is too early for all fixtures to be executed; use [`pytest_pyfunc_call`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#_pytest.hookspec.pytest_pyfunc_call) instead. Example:

```
from _pytest.fixtures import FixtureRequest


def pytest_pyfunc_call(pyfuncitem):
    if 'db' in pyfuncitem.fixturenames:
        db = FixtureRequest(pyfuncitem, _ispytest=True).getfixturevalue('db')
        db.session.commit()
    # ensure this hook returns None, or your underlying test function won't be executed.
```

**Warning:** `pytest.FixtureRequest()` is considered non-public by the pytest maintainers for anything except type-hinting. That’s why its use issues a deprecation warning without the `_ispytest=True` flag. The API might change without a major release. There is [no public API yet](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/8832#issuecomment-871229389) that supports this use-case. (Last updated for pytest 6.2.5)

Comment: pytest marks the usage of `FixtureRequest` now as deprecated. Do you also have suggestions for a non-deprecated method?

Comment: pytest [does not offer a pulic API for manipulating fixtures](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/8832#issuecomment-871229389) yet. The deprecation warnings can be silenced for now by using `FixtureRequest(pyfuncitem, _ispytest=True)`. Be aware that this is using pytest internals. // Can’t suggest an edit as the review queue is full atm.

Comment: The usage of `FixtureRequest` per se is not deprecated in any way; it's actually even exposed for typing purposes via `from pytest import FixtureRequest`. However, especially due to that, the warning makes sense to make you aware of using `pytest` internal stuff, even though it can be imported from the public package. I wouldn't just silence this one at all, or at least do that via `filterwarnings` with a proper explanation in the comment.

Comment: `@pytest.mark.filterwarnings` doesn’t seem to work for hook implementations though.

Comment: I prefer the comment/explanation to be *near* the code it is about. So I don’t see putting the filterwarnings statement in the config as a good option. I think I’ll stick with `_ispytest=True` for now.